# EF: checking if object has been modified

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a `Listview` with objects.
When I select an item from the `Listview`, I need to know if the `selectedObject` of the `Listview` has been modified to activate or not a `saveButton`.

This is how I proceed using Mvvmlight and Entity Framework 5 :

```
public RelayCommand SaveObjectCommand { get; set; }

public MainViewModel()
{
    SaveObjectCommand = new RelayCommand(SaveObject, CanSaveObject);
}

private bool CanSaveObject()
{
     using (DBContext ctx = new DBContext())
     {
         //selectedObject is the object selected from the Listview
         Object dbObject = ctx.Object.Single(x => x.ID == selectedObject.ID);

         if (selectedObject == dbObject) //simplified
             return false; 
     }     
}
```

That's working but it's quite slow.
In fact each time I select an object from the listview, I request the DB to know if `selectedObject` is equal to the same object in DB (my way to know if the selectedObject properties have been modified)

Is there a better way to do that?
I've heard about DBContext.ChangeTracker but it seems that it needs a DB request to.

Comment: When do changes occur for it to be modified? When it gets persisted or modified on the UI, or what? When one of the properties are modified on the actual object? Hitting the database per selectionchange is not a good idea.

Comment: I think it's not a good idea too, that's the point of my question :).
I've got textboxes in which I can modify the selectedObject properties

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comment.
What DB are you using? Is it compact?

And a workaround for your question: you can declare property

```
private List<Object> MyCollectionOfObjects {get; set;}
```

with your own collection and access to it in CanSaveObject() wethod. If DB needs for update you should update DB and this property.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL but I don't think it's important.
Anyway I edited my question because I think I was not clear enough

Comment: If you using MSSQL compact edition it's very important. If not i can't help unless my suggestion in answer :(

Comment: Actually, I'm using MSSQL with Windows Azure, don't know the edition

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned, your `textblocks` probably `textboxes` can modify the selected object properties where you will check if that object `CanSave`. I recommend looking at [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface

A quick sample

```
public class Customer : IEditableObject 
{

    struct CustomerData 
    {
        internal string id ;
        internal string firstName ;
        internal string lastName ;
    }

    private CustomersList parent;
    private CustomerData custData; 
    private CustomerData backupData; 
    private bool inTxn = false;

    // Implements IEditableObject 
    void IEditableObject.BeginEdit() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start BeginEdit");
        if (!inTxn) 
        {
            this.backupData = custData;
            inTxn = true;
            Console.WriteLine("BeginEdit - " + this.backupData.lastName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End BeginEdit");
    }

    void IEditableObject.CancelEdit() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start CancelEdit");
        if (inTxn) 
        {
            this.custData = backupData;
            inTxn = false;
            Console.WriteLine("CancelEdit - " + this.custData.lastName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End CancelEdit");
    }

    void IEditableObject.EndEdit() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start EndEdit" + this.custData.id + this.custData.lastName);
        if (inTxn) 
        {
            backupData = new CustomerData();
            inTxn = false;
            Console.WriteLine("Done EndEdit - " + this.custData.id + this.custData.lastName);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("End EndEdit");
    }

    public Customer(string ID) : base() 
    {
        this.custData = new CustomerData();
        this.custData.id = ID;
        this.custData.firstName = "";
        this.custData.lastName = "";
    }

    public string ID 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.custData.id;
        }
    }

    public string FirstName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.custData.firstName;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.custData.firstName = value;
            this.OnCustomerChanged();
        }
    }

    public string LastName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.custData.lastName;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.custData.lastName = value;
            this.OnCustomerChanged();
        }
    }

    internal CustomersList Parent 
    {
        get 
        {
            return parent;
        }
        set 
        {
            parent = value ;
        }
    }

    private void OnCustomerChanged() 
    {
        if (!inTxn && Parent != null) 
        {
            Parent.CustomerChanged(this);
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() 
    {
        StringWriter sb = new StringWriter();
        sb.Write(this.FirstName);
        sb.Write(" ");
        sb.Write(this.LastName);
        return sb.ToString();
    }   
}
```

> I request the DB to know if selectedObject is equal to the same
>   object in DB (my way to know if the selectedObject properties have
>   been modified)

In your case it's better to do the check against in memory instead of going to the database and see if any of the values are different to what was inputted.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. In facts I meant textboxes ;). Your solution seems to be about what I'm searching for.
Unfortunately, my classes are auto-generated by EF and I cannot modify them.

Comment: Do a partial class on your `POCO` classes or you can make T4 template to do that for you. But since then, you are doing it wrong you don't want to bound the actual Model to the View. You are breaking MVVM pattern. You want a Model inside a ViewModel and you wrap the properties of the Model to the ViewModel's properties.